# Extracting from excel (.xlsx) writing to .txt file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, extract, data-extraction

*Background*: Excel file with 3 columns and approx 10,000 rows. Columns for: Name, Address and Email. Rows for corresponding data.

Tried the following code to extract every entry in the excel file and save in separate file with the name of the person. Like a "business card".

The `.txt` files are generated, but they are empty -- i.e. no data written in the files.

Where is the code going wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import openpyxl as opx
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fileName = r'\...\Name Extraction Text files\TestBook.xlsx'
sheetName = "Sheet1"

wb2 = load_workbook(fileName)
ws4 = wb2["Sheet1"]

maxRows = sheet.max_row
>>> 10001
maxCol = sheet.max_column
>>> 3

for i in range(1, maxRows + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    outputFile = open(r'\...\ExtractedFiles\{}.txt'.format(name), 'w')

for j in range(1, maxCol + 1):
    outputFile.write(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value + '\n')
    outputFile.seek(0)

#checking for the count
print('Written file number: {}'.format(i))

print('Done writing your business cards.')
```

EDIT: First tried with the `.close()` function, but gives the error `I/O operation on closed file.` so this attempt with `.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to make a txt file for each row? You need to close the file that has been written before doing another one.

```
outputFile.close()
```

You also may want to supply 'w+' to the open function.

Check this out 
https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html

ADDITION:

```
for i in range(1, maxRows + 1):
    name = ws4.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    outputFile = open('test{}.txt'.format(name), 'w+')
    for j in range(1, maxCol + 1):
        outputFile.write(ws4.cell(row=i, column=j).value + "\n")
    outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Shane G. 
That's right. However, already tried the `.close()` option. But I get the error "I/O Operation on closed file.". Any workarounds for this?

Comment: @mvx You have a nesting problem with your loops. You shouldn't use seek() at all.

Comment: @mvx You have a lot of references that are incorrect and not used in your code snippet.

Comment: Yep, the the nesting is the problem. Just figured it out a few minutes ago. Thanks a lot for your help @Shane G! :)

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd forloop is outside the 1rst loop. It needs to be inside the 1rst forloop.

Comment: Yep, just figured it out a few minutes ago! Thanks @Rizvi :)

Comment: Don't know, who downvoted this. The observation was obviously right. I upvoted to correct this. It's a shame how downvotes are used here sometimes!